# Loading an image for a set amount of time in pygame

Tags: image, time, pygame

Does anyone know how to load an image when you click a button that will then go after about 10/15 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

First of all check this https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html (or some tutorials).

`im = pygame.image.load(path_to_file).convert_alpha()` loads an image to im

```
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
```

That's a surface that is your screen, everything blits into it.

```
if not stopDisplay:
    surface.blit(im, (x, y))
```

Your image then appears on screen at (x,y) coordinates.

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            terminate()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mx, my = event.dict.get('pos')
```

This included in the main loop of a program will assign mouse coords to mx and my on click.

Check the time however you want, there are plenty of ways.

If the mouse coords are in your image rectangle, that is

```
if x <= mx <= im.get_width() and y <= my <= im.get_height() and time > 15:
    stopDisplay = True
```

Stop displaying an image simply by not blitting it